# How can I get value from a table in module and filter a table in a second module?

Tags: python, py-shiny

I am building a python shiny app that will use a row value selected from a table in a given module to filter a second table that will be rendered in another module.

```py
# file1.py

python
from shiny import req, ui, module, render, reactive
import shiny.experimental as x
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])


@module.ui
def table_view_ui(label: str = "Table"):
    
    return x.ui.card(
        {"style": "color:#000"},
        x.ui.card_header("This is " + label), 
        ui.output_data_frame("grided"),
         ui.output_text("select_row")
)

@module.server
def table_server(input, output, session):
    # Render Table
    @output
    @render.data_frame
    def grided():
        {"style": "color:#000"},
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        
        return render.DataGrid(
            df.reset_index(),
            row_selection_mode="single", 
            width=width,
            filters=True,
            height=height)

    @output
    @render.text 
    def select_row():
       
       if (input.grided_selected_rows() is not None
            and len(input.grided_selected_rows()) > 0
        ):
            selected_idx = list(req(input.grided_selected_rows()))
            selected_row= df.iloc[selected_idx]

            value_selected = selected_row["num_legs"].values[0]
            return value_selected
```

on another python file (file 2), the goal is to use extract the value selected (`value_selected`) and filter another table. At this stage, I can render the table on file2.py but I've not been able to get the value returned.

```py
 
  # file2.py

from shiny import req, ui, module, render, reactive

from .file1 import table_view_ui, table_server

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_eyes': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [4, 0, 2, 1]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

@module.ui
def second_table_ui():
    return ui.tags.div(
    table_view("table_viewer")

@module.server
def second_server(input, output, session):
    table_server("table_viewer")
```

If I can capture the row value selected in `file1.py` from `df`, I will be able to filter another dataframe (`df2`) in `file2.py`.

```py
# file3.py

from shiny import req, ui, module, render, reactive, App

from .file2 import second_table_ui, second_server

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
   second_table_ui("second_table_viewer")

def server(input, output, session):
   second_server("second_table_viewer")
 
app = App(app_ui, server)
```